# How do I change the time zone of a Google Cloud Windows Server 2016 VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016

When I try to change the time zone of a Windows Server 2016 VM on Google Cloud Platform I get a permissions error. My user has full admin privileges. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must open the timezone settings via `Server Manager`.... I attached a screenshot for your ease.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm this works in 2022! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the timezone through the Server Manager, not the control panel. Nothing to do with GCP.

Comment: Yes, strangest thing, it doesn't work through control panel.  Has nothing to do with GCP, time servers, etc .